# Fluctuation of MySQL Performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a MySQL (MyISAM) database with different tables. Lets take for example the database "rh955_omf" with the following tables:

- signal (600 MBytes, 17925 entries)
- picture (5'355 MBytes, 17925 entries)
- velocity (680 MBytes, 4979 entries)

Actually I'm just concentrating onto the signal table entries. Therefore I want to describe this table a bit better. It's created as following:

```
CREATE TABLE rh955_omf.signal(MeasNr TINYINT UNSIGNED, ExperimentNr TINYINT UNSIGNED, Time INT, SequenceNr SMALLINT UNSIGNED, MeanBeatRate SMALLINT UNSIGNED, MedBeatRate SMALLINT UNSIGNED, MeanAmp1 MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, MeanAmp2 MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, StdDeviationAmp1 DOUBLE, StdDeviationAmp2 DOUBLE, MeanDeltaAmp MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, Offset INT UNSIGNED, NrOfPeaks SMALLINT UNSIGNED, `Signal` MEDIUMBLOB, Peakcoord MEDIUMBLOB, Validity BOOL, Comment VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(MeasNr, ExperimentNr, SequenceNr));
```

I load the values from this table with the following command:

```
SELECT MeanBeatRate FROM rh955_omf.signal WHERE MeasNr = 3 AND ExperimentNr = 10 AND SequenceNr BETWEEN 0 AND 407
```

If I load the whole "MeanBeatRate" row (int 16 values) for the first time, it takes me about 54 seconds (MeasNr = 1..3, ExperimentNr = 1..24, SequenceNr >= min AND <= max). If I load it again, it takes 0.5 seconds (cache).

So what I want to do is speeding up the database. Therefore, I created some new databases, but didn't put all the tables into the different databases:

- rh955_copy_omf: signal table
- rh955_p_copy_omf: signal table, picture table
- rh955_v_p_copy_omf: signal table, picture table, velocity table

I restarted the computer and loaded all the "MeanBeatRate" values from the different tables. That gave me the following time:

- rh955_omf: 54s (as mentioned before)
- rh955_copy_omf: 3.1s
- rh955_p_copy_omf: 12.9s
- rh955_v_p_copy_omf: 10.7s

So it looks like the time to load the data is dependent of the other tables in the database. Is this even possible (because I'm just searching in the "signal" table)? And what is even more confusing: In the table "rh955_v_p_copy_omf" I have all the data I also have in the original table, but the performance is ~5 times better. Any explanation for that behavior? I would be thankful for any help because I'm really stuck at this point and need to increase the database performance...

**Additional information:** In one case, I stored the data in the table with the command "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/Exported MySQL/rh955/signal.omf' INTO table rh955_omf.signal" (that's the case where loading data is slow), in the other cases I stored the data line by line. Maybe that's the case why the performance is different? If yes, what's the workaround to store data from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Are they indexed the same?

Are the server parameters the same  for each DB (same memory, start up configuration and parameters, etc)?

Are they on the same disk?

If they are on the same disk is there some other application running at the same time which influences where the read-write heads are?

Do you stop the other databases each time or have some still running some times?

Comment: that are a lot of questions for an answer ;-)

Comment: I'm running the database locally. So everything is on the same disk. There should not be a (big) influence of other applications which are running at the same time. I have just running one database at the same time.

Comment: I would still wonder about the underlying disk.  You 54 seconds for one DB on first load; I assume that this is "rh955_omf: 54s (as mentioned before)" and the the other figures in the comparison are first loads - disk is likely to affect this.  Fragmentation, etc.  Or explain plans (indexing, etc)  Are they using the same access path?

Comment: Yes they are using the same access path. The problem is: I did several measurements like this, with always the same result, that's why I don't think the location on the disk is not the cause of this problem.

Comment: Additional information: In one case, I imported the data with the command "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/Exported MySQL/rh955/signal.omf' INTO table rh955_omf.signal" (that's the case where loading data is slow), in the other cases I stored the data line by line. Maybe the difference is there???